# inserting the src file in dynamically to audio tag and storing src name in html code

Tags: jquery, html, audio, dynamic

I have been writing some code that plays audio files. I've used the one audio player and when one button is clicked, corresponding src files ogg and mp3 are dynamically inserted into the source tags of the audio player. The only way I could see to do this (while also trying to avoid an inline javascript onclick event handler) is as follows. I have the directory of the mp3 file and the ogg file stored in a div tag with an id. and then have hidden the tag with css. (This filename will be extracted from a database) Anyway, I have a feeling this is not a good practise to have content hidden in a div like that. and I always try to keep up with best practises. Have you any thoughts and what could be better? thanks

My html:

```
    <ul id='audio_list'>

                <li class='gradient_blackblue'>

                    <div class='audio_controls_area'>
                    <div id='timer'></div>
                        <div class='circle'></div>
                        <div class ='play_pause'>
                            <div class='play button_style' id='btnPlayPause0'><i class='fa fa-play'></i>
                            <div id='file_mp3'>music/electronic beat-monksee.mp3</div>
                            <div id='file_ogg'>music/electronic beat-monksee.ogg</div>
                            </div>  
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class='audio_description'>Electro Soundz
                        <div id='slider_area'>
                        <span id='songTime0' class='songTime'>0:00</span>
                        <input id='sliderTime0' class='slider' type='range' min='0' value='0'/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </li>


                <li class='gradient_blackblue'>
                    <div class='audio_controls_area'>
                        <div id='timer'></div>
                        <div class='circle'></div>
                        <div class ='play_pause'>
                            <div class='play button_style' id='btnPlayPause1'><i class='fa fa-play'></i>
                                <div id='file_mp3'>music/dubstep.mp3</div>
                                <div id='file_ogg'>music/dubstep.mp3</div>
                            </div>  
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class='audio_description'>Dubstep beat
                        <div id='slider_area'>
                        <span id='songTime1' class='songTime'>0:00</span>
                        <input id='sliderTime1' class='slider' type='range' min='0' value='0' />
                        </div>
                    </div>

            </li>
</ul>

    <audio id ='audio_player'>
    <source id='src_mp3' type='audio/mp3'/>
    <source id='src_ogg' type='audio/ogg'/>
    <object id='audio_object' type='audio/x-mpeg' width='200px' height='45px' >
            <param id = 'param_src' name='src'/>
            <param name='autoplay' value='false' />
            <param name='autostart' value='false' />
        </object>
    </audio>
```

My css:

```
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body{


}

.play_pause {
 width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 15px;
  position: relative;

}

.play_pause .button_style{
  cursor: pointer;
width:100%;
height:100%;
display: block;
position: relative;
border-radius: 50%;
border-bottom: 1px outset #1532AE;
color: #fff; /*color of play before pressed*/
font-size: 30px;
text-align: center;
line-height: 50px;
background: rgb(9,178,249); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(9,178,249,1) 0%, rgba(11,164,237,1) 15%, rgba(20,76,173,1) 73%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(9,178,249,1)), color-stop(15%,rgba(11,164,237,1)), color-stop(73%,rgba(20,76,173,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(9,178,249,1) 0%,rgba(11,164,237,1) 15%,rgba(20,76,173,1) 73%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(9,178,249,1) 0%,rgba(11,164,237,1) 15%,rgba(20,76,173,1) 73%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(9,178,249,1) 0%,rgba(11,164,237,1) 15%,rgba(20,76,173,1) 73%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(9,178,249,1) 0%,rgba(11,164,237,1) 15%,rgba(20,76,173,1) 73%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#09b2f9', endColorstr='#144cad',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
z-index: 1;
}

.play_pause .play{
box-shadow:
    inset 0 2px 3px rgba(255,255,255,0.13),
    0 5px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3),
    0 8px 10px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.6); /*this is what makes it look like it is being pressed*/
text-shadow: 0 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.25); /*the middle text*/
}

.play_pause .button_style:before {
  content: ""; 
  position: absolute;
  left: -8px;
  right: -8px;
  top: -8px;
  bottom: -8px;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: inherit;
  box-shadow: inset 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.13); 
  -webkit-filter:blur(1px); /*smooth trick*/
  -moz-filter:blur(1px);
  -ms-filter:blur(1px);
  -o-filter:blur(1px);
  filter: blur(1px); /*future proof*/

}

.play_pause .button_style:after {
  content: ""; 
  position: absolute;
  left: -8px;
  right: -8px;
  top: -8px;
  bottom: -8px;
  z-index: -2;
  border-radius: inherit;
box-shadow:
    inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,1), /*tried changin but its just blue line around outside*/
    0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3),
    0 0 10px rgba(5,52,140,1); /*outside shadow line*/
  }

.play_pause .isPlaying { /*button*/
  box-shadow:
    inset 0 2px 3px rgba(157,157,157,0.13),
    0 5px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.35),
    -1px -1px 8px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
text-shadow: rgb(70, 70, 70) -1px -1px 1px;
} 


.play_pause .fa-play:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 70%;
  height: 70%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
  margin: -37% 0 0 -40%;

}

.play_pause .fa-stop{
content: "";
display: block;
position: absolute;
width: 70%;
height: 70%;
left: 13%;
top: 21%;
font-size: 26px;
z-index: -2;
}


.circle {
  content: ""; 
  position: absolute;
background: #fff;
left: 10%;

  top: 9%;
width: 64px;
height: 64px;
  z-index: -50;
  border-radius: 50%;
}


#timer{
position: absolute;
left: 10%;
top: 9%;
width: 64px;
height: 64px;
  z-index: -45;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#timer:before, #timer.timer{
display: none;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 6px;
    height: 64px;
    left: 46%;

    z-index: -1;
    background: url(timer.png) 0 0 no-repeat;

}


#file_mp3{
display: none;

}
#file_ogg{
display: none;

}
```

Javscript and jquery:

```
var player;
    var intv;
    var slider;
    var max;
    var duration;

    //init
    window.onload = function(){
    player = document.getElementById('audio_player');
    }


    function playMusic(songTime, button){
    player.play();
    intv = setInterval(function() { update(songTime, button); }, 100);
    $(player).on("loadeddata", function(){
            window.degreePerSecond = 360/window.duration;
            $(window.timer).addClass('timer');
            $('#timer.timer').css({
            'display':'block'

            });
    });


    }

    function pauseMusic(){
    player.pause();
    clearInterval(intv);
    }

    function stopMusic(){
    player.pause();
    player.currentTime = 0;
    clearInterval(intv);
    }

    function reposition(){
    var reposition_value = $(slider).val();
    player.currentTime = reposition_value;

    }

    function update(songTime, button){
    $(songTime).html(millisToMins(player.currentTime));
    $(slider).val(player.currentTime);
    var current = player.currentTime;

    var degreeCurrent = (window.degreePerSecond*current);
    $(window.timer).css({
    '-webkit-transform':'rotate(' + degreeCurrent + 'deg)',
    '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degreeCurrent + 'deg)',
    '-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + degreeCurrent + 'deg)',
    '-o-transform' : 'rotate(' + degreeCurrent + 'deg)',
    'transform' : 'rotate(' + degreeCurrent + 'deg)'
    });

    if ((player.duration > 0) && (player.currentTime== player.duration)){
        $(button).addClass("play").removeClass("isPlaying");
        $(button).children("i").addClass("fa-play").removeClass("fa-stop");
        $(window.timer).removeClass('timer');
        $(window.timer).removeAttr('style');

        //alert("player duration");
        stopMusic();

    }

    }

    function millisToMins(seconds){
    var numminutes = Math.floor((((seconds % 31536000) % 86400) % 3600) / 60);
    var numseconds = (((seconds % 31536000) % 86400) % 3600) % 60;
    if (numseconds >= 10){
    return numminutes + ":" + Math.round(numseconds);
    }else{
    return numminutes + ":0" + Math.round(numseconds);
    }
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('li .button_style').click(function(){
            $(window.timer).removeClass('timer');
            $(window.timer).removeAttr('style');
            //console.log($(window.timer).closest('li').html());
            clearInterval(intv);

        if($(this).hasClass("isPlaying")){
            pauseMusic();
            $(this).addClass("play").removeClass("isPlaying");
            $(this).children("i").addClass("fa-play").removeClass("fa-stop");

        }else if($(this).hasClass("play")){
            var mp3 = $('> #file_mp3', this).html();
            var ogg = $('> #file_ogg', this).html();
            $('#src_mp3').attr('src', mp3);
            $('#src_ogg').attr('src', ogg);
            $('#audio_object').attr('data', mp3);
            $('#param_src').attr('value', mp3);
            player.load();

            songTime = $('.songTime', $(this).closest('li'));
            window.timer = $('#timer', $(this).closest('li'));
            slider = $('.slider', $(this).closest('li'));
            $(slider).on('change', reposition);
            $(player).on("loadeddata", function(){
                window.duration = player.duration;
                $(slider).attr('max', window.duration);
            });

            var button = $(this);
            playMusic(songTime, button);
            $(".button_style").addClass("play").removeClass("isPlaying");
            $("div").children("i").addClass("fa-play").removeClass("fa-stop");
            $(this).children("i").removeClass("fa-play").addClass("fa-stop");
            $(this).removeClass("play").addClass("isPlaying");
        console.log($('#audio_list').html());
        }
    });



});
```

A jsfiddle of the code
http://jsfiddle.net/LAZay/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this. When loading in the files from a database with php. I store the mp3 and the ogg file directories into two php arrays instead of putting them in a hidden div. Which I then convert into a javascript array and when the corresponding play button is pressed eg btnPlaypause0 then the mp3array[0] source file will be inserted into the source attribute of the audio tag and then played. here's my html/php code:

```
<?php
    require("music_connect.php");       
    $mp3_php = array();
    $ogg_php = array();
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM products");
    if (!$result) {
            printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
            exit();
    }

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        array_push($mp3_php, $row['Productmp3']);
        array_push($ogg_php, $row['ProductOgg']);
    }

?>
```

```
    <?php

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM products");
    if (!$result) {
            printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
            exit();
    }
    echo "<ul id='audio_list'>";
    $x = 0;
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

            echo "<li class='gradient_blackblue'>
            <div class='audio_controls_area'>
                <div id='timer" . $x . "' class='timer_style timer_small'></div>
                <div class='circle'></div>
                <div class ='play_pause'>
                <div class='play button_style' id='btnPlayPause" . $x . "'><i class='fa fa-play'></i></div> 
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class='audio_description'>" . $row['ProductName'] . "
                <div class='artist'>" . $row['ProductArtist'] . "</div>
                <div id='slider_area'>
                <span id='songTime" . $x . "' class='songTime'>0:00</span>
                <input id='slider" . $x . "' class='slider' type='range' min='0' value='0' />
                </div>

            </div>
            <a href='electro_soundz.php'><i class='fa fa-chevron-right'></i></a>
            </li>";
            $x++;

        }
    echo "</ul>";
    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>


<audio id ='audio_player'>
<source id='src_mp3' type='audio/mp3'/>
<source id='src_ogg' type='audio/ogg'/>
<object id='audio_object' type='audio/x-mpeg' width='200px' height='45px' >
        <param id = 'param_src' name='src'/>
        <param name='autoplay' value='false' />
        <param name='autostart' value='false' />
    </object>
</audio>
```

and javascript:

```
    <script>

        var player;
        var intv;
        var slider;
        var songTime;
        var max;
        var duration;

        //init
        window.onload = function(){

            player = document.getElementById('audio_player');

            window.mp3_array= <?php echo json_encode($mp3_php); ?>;
            window.ogg_array= <?php echo json_encode($ogg_php); ?>;
            var mp3_length = window.mp3_array.length;
                for(var i=0;i<mp3_length;i++){
            listenForI(i);
                }
            console.log(window.mp3_array);
            console.log(window.ogg_array);

        }
        function listenForI(i){
            document.getElementById('btnPlayPause' + i).addEventListener('click', function() { songSelect(i); }, false);
        }
        function playMusic(songTime, button){
    player.play();
    intv = setInterval(function() { update(songTime, button); }, 100);
}


function pauseMusic(){
    player.pause();
    clearInterval(intv);
}

function stopMusic(){
    player.pause();
    player.currentTime = 0;
    clearInterval(intv);
}

function reposition(){
    var reposition_value = $(slider).val();
    player.currentTime = reposition_value;

}

function update(songTime, button){
    document.getElementById(songTime).innerHTML = millisToMins(player.currentTime);
    $(slider).val(player.currentTime);
    var current = player.currentTime;
    var degreeCurrent = (window.degreePerSecond*current);
    $(window.timer).css({
    '-webkit-transform':'rotate(' + degreeCurrent + 'deg)',
    '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degreeCurrent + 'deg)',
    '-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + degreeCurrent + 'deg)',
    '-o-transform' : 'rotate(' + degreeCurrent + 'deg)',
    'transform' : 'rotate(' + degreeCurrent + 'deg)'
    });

    if ((player.duration > 0) && (player.currentTime== player.duration)){
        $(button).addClass("play").removeClass("isPlaying");
        $(button).children("i").addClass("fa-play").removeClass("fa-stop");
        $(window.timer).removeClass('timer');
        $(window.timer).removeAttr('style');
        stopMusic();    
    }

}

function millisToMins(seconds){
    var numminutes = Math.floor((((seconds % 31536000) % 86400) % 3600) / 60);
    var numseconds = (((seconds % 31536000) % 86400) % 3600) % 60;
    if (numseconds >= 10){
        return numminutes + ":" + Math.round(numseconds);
    }else{
        return numminutes + ":0" + Math.round(numseconds);
    }
}

function songSelect(x){
    $(window.timer).removeClass('timer');
    $(window.timer).removeAttr('style');
    clearInterval(intv);
    var button = '#' + 'btnPlayPause' + x;
    if($(button).hasClass("isPlaying")){
        pauseMusic();
        $(button).addClass("play").removeClass("isPlaying");
        $(button).children("i").addClass("fa-play").removeClass("fa-stop");
    }else if($(button).hasClass("play")){
        var mp3 = window.mp3_array[x];
        var ogg = window.ogg_array[x];
        $('#src_mp3').attr('src', mp3);
        $('#src_ogg').attr('src', ogg);
        $('#audio_object').attr('data', mp3);
        $('#param_src').attr('value', mp3);
        console.log($('#audio_player').html());
        player.load();
        songTime = 'songTime' + x;
        window.timer = '#timer' + x;
        slider = '#slider' + x;
        $(slider).on('change', reposition);
        $(player).on("loadeddata", function(){
            window.duration = player.duration;
            $(slider).attr('max', window.duration);
            window.degreePerSecond = 360/window.duration;
            $(window.timer).addClass('timer');
            $('.timer_style.timer').css({
                'display':'block'

            });
        });
        playMusic(songTime, button);
        $("div").addClass("play").removeClass("isPlaying");
        $("div").children("i").addClass("fa-play").removeClass("fa-stop");
        $(button).children("i").removeClass("fa-play").addClass("fa-stop");
        $(button).removeClass("play").addClass("isPlaying");    
    }
}




    </script>
```